# reshape to wide format, while varying only a single column at a time (for sensitivity analysis)

Tags: r, data.table

There are already many Q&A's relating to reshaping data, but I did not find one that deals with this specific case.

I want to take a long format table that provides low, average and high values for an arbitrary number of parameters, with values varying over an arbitrary number of groups.  Here is a simple example table with just two parameters (f1, f2) and two groups (A, B).

```
library(data.table)
input = fread("
grp variable value level
A   f1       0.1   low
A   f1       0.2   average
A   f1       0.3   high
A   f2       0.5   low
A   f2       0.6   average
A   f2       0.7   high
B   f1       1.0   low
B   f1       2.0   average
B   f1       3.0   high
B   f2       -10   low
B   f2       -5    average
B   f2       0     high
")
```

To conduct sensitivity analyses, I would like to convert this to a table in which each parameter is varied from low to high, while fixing all other parameters at their average value (for each group).

The expected output for the simple example would look like this:

```
expected = fread("
grp  variable    level  f1   f2
A    f1          low   0.1  0.6
A    f1          high  0.3  0.6
A    f2          low   0.2  0.5
A    f2          high  0.2  0.7
B    f1          low   1.0  -5
B    f1          high  3.0  -5
B    f2          low   2.0  -10
B    f2          high  2.0  0
")
```

I can find the varying factors for each sensitivity, using `dcast`:

```
dcast(input, grp + variable + level ~ variable)[level != 'average']
#    grp sensitivity level  f1    f2
# 1:   A          f1  high 0.3    NA
# 2:   A          f1   low 0.1    NA
# 3:   A          f2  high  NA   0.7
# 4:   A          f2   low  NA   0.5
# 5:   B          f1  high 3.0    NA
# 6:   B          f1   low 1.0    NA
# 7:   B          f2  high  NA   0.0
# 8:   B          f2   low  NA -10.0
```

But, I did not find a neat way to also fill in the average values for the other factors that works for any number of groups and factors.  I'm really interested in base or `data.table` solutions, but other packages also welcome as they could help others.

---

Here's a slightly larger input table with 3 parameters and 3 groups, to test solutions on:

```
structure(list(grp = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), variable = c("f1", "f1", "f1", 
"f2", "f2", "f2", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f2", "f2", 
"f2", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f3", 
"f3", "f3"), value = c(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 4, 5, 6, 
1, 2, 3, -10, -5, 0, 11, 12, 13, 100, 200, 300, 3, 6, 9, 21, 
22, 23), level = c("low", "average", "high", "low", "average", 
"high", "low", "average", "high", "low", "average", "high", "low", 
"average", "high", "low", "average", "high", "low", "average", 
"high", "low", "average", "high", "low", "average", "high")), row.names = c(NA, 
-27L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

---

In case it helps, we can also generate larger input tables to test using the following.  My current use case has nearly 10,000 groups and ~25 parameters.

```
Ngrp = 5
Nf = 7
grp = 1:Ngrp
f = paste0("f", 1:Nf)
input = expand.grid(grp = grp, variable=f, level = c("low", "average", "high"))
setDT(input)
setkey(input, grp, variable, level)
input[level == 'low',     value := rnorm(.N, grp,    grp/10), by=.(grp,variable)]
input[level == 'average', value := rnorm(.N, grp*5,  grp/2), by=.(grp,variable)]
input[level == 'high',    value := rnorm(.N, grp*10, grp), by=.(grp,variable)]
```

Comment: What's the logic of output? F1 and f2 values are mixed together??

Comment: For example what does row 1&2 last col in output means? Or rows 3&4 in penultimate col means?

Comment: @AnilGoyal every row has a column value for every parameter.  For every parameter/group there  are two rows in the output: 1) where that parameter takes its low value and all other parameters are average; 2) where that parameter takes its high value and all other parameters are average.

Comment: but what if in case of three Fs like in the dput?

Comment: @AnilGoyal with three f's, the logic stays the same.  We would provide a high and low row for each f, while keeping all other f's at their average.

Comment: Please see the `tidyverse` strategy.  I am not that well versed with `data.table` package, but see if you or someone can translate it to DT syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `data.table` we could also do:

```
f <- function(x, y)nafill(x, "const", na.omit(x[y=="average"]))

dcast(input, grp + variable + level ~ variable)[,
      rapply(.SD, f, "numeric", how="replace", y=level), by=grp][level !="average"]


   grp variable level  f1    f2
1:   A       f1  high 0.3   0.6
2:   A       f1   low 0.1   0.6
3:   A       f2  high 0.2   0.7
4:   A       f2   low 0.2   0.5
5:   B       f1  high 3.0  -5.0
6:   B       f1   low 1.0  -5.0
7:   B       f2  high 2.0   0.0
8:   B       f2   low 2.0 -10.0
```

Comment: Excellent solution!!! I had to make a slight edit to the function, to catch cases where x has only NA for a group/parameter combination. `f <- function(x, y)  if (length(na.omit(x))) {nafill(x, "const", na.omit(x[y=="mean"])) } else {nafill(x, "const", NA)}`

Comment: @dww why not just do `f<- function(x,y) if(all(is.na(x)) x else nafill(x, "const", na.omit(x[y=="mean"])) `? Why do you want to do `nafill` with `NA` in the else part? Its already `NA` just retain it as such, no need to pass it to the `nafill` function

Comment: yes, of course that is much simpler - I did not think about it much, just quickly typed code to check it worked.  BTW, this is the first time I saw `rapply` used - interesting and useful looking function.

Comment: @dww I see. You can use `lapply` but in this case, I would rather prefer `rapply` since it is succinct

Answer (score 1):

I suggest a two step strategy.  I was actually trying to do it in one syntax (i.e. without creating intermediate `df1` but wasn't able to figure out how to use `arguments` when one lambda function is passed within another one in `purrr` style of writing functions).  Nevertheless, since your final values are cross matching you indeed have to follow a longer route.  This is only based on assumption that your sensitivity levels start from character `f`.

#### step-1 create intermediate df1

```
library(tidyverse)

merge(df %>% 
        select(v1 = variable) %>% 
        unique(), 
      df %>% 
        select(v2 = variable) %>% 
        unique(), 
      all.x = T) %>%
  full_join(df , by = c('v1' = 'variable')) %>%
  filter(level != 'average') %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = c(grp, v1, level),
              names_from = v2,
              values_from = value) -> df1
```

#### final step

```
library(glue)

df %>% filter(level == 'average') %>%
  mutate(variable = paste0('av_', variable)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = grp, names_from = variable, values_from = value) %>%
  right_join(df1, by = "grp") %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("f"), ~ifelse(v1 != cur_column(),
                                          get(glue('av_{cur_column()}')),
                                          .)
                )
         ) %>%
  select(grp, variable = v1, level, starts_with("f")) 

# A tibble: 18 x 6
   grp   variable level    f1    f2    f3
   <chr> <chr>    <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 A     f1       low     0.1   0.6     5
 2 A     f1       high    0.3   0.6     5
 3 A     f2       low     0.2   0.5     5
 4 A     f2       high    0.2   0.7     5
 5 A     f3       low     0.2   0.6     4
 6 A     f3       high    0.2   0.6     6
 7 B     f1       low     1    -5      12
 8 B     f1       high    3    -5      12
 9 B     f2       low     2   -10      12
10 B     f2       high    2     0      12
11 B     f3       low     2    -5      11
12 B     f3       high    2    -5      13
13 C     f1       low   100     6      22
14 C     f1       high  300     6      22
15 C     f2       low   200     3      22
16 C     f2       high  200     9      22
17 C     f3       low   200     6      21
18 C     f3       high  200     6      23
```

The two steps are actually for better understanding.  Two steps can be combined within one single pipe

```
df %>% filter(level == 'average') %>%
  mutate(variable = paste0('av_', variable)) %>%
  pivot_wider(id_cols = grp, names_from = variable, values_from = value) %>%
  right_join(merge(df %>% 
                     select(v1 = variable) %>% 
                     unique(), 
                   df %>% 
                     select(v2 = variable) %>% 
                     unique(), 
                   all.x = T) %>%
               full_join(df , by = c('v1' = 'variable')) %>%
               filter(level != 'average') %>%
               pivot_wider(id_cols = c(grp, v1, level),
                           names_from = v2,
                           values_from = value), by = "grp") %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("f"), ~ifelse(v1 != cur_column(),
                                          get(glue('av_{cur_column()}')),
                                          .)
                )
         ) %>%
  select(grp, variable = v1, level, starts_with("f"))
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer - it looks like a lot of effort went into it which is very much appreciated.  I managed in the mean time to find a decent data.table solution (see my answer), which is what I was more looking for.  But, your answer can also be useful to others that use dplyr.

Answer (score 0):

I found a data.table method using a row-wise loop:

```
out = dcast(input, grp + variable + level ~ variable)[level != 'average']
fs = input[, unique(variable)] # vector of unique parmeter names
f = function(g,v) input[grp==g & variable != v & level=="average", as.list(value)]
for (i in seq_len(nrow(out))) {
  set(out, i, setdiff(fs, out[i,variable]), out[i, f(grp, variable)]) 
}
```